# fish shell changes how git stash references work. How to configure the shell to fix this?

Tags: git, fish

I started to use fish shell and everything was going well...until I tried to work with stashes.

For some reason:
`git stash show -p stash@{1}` would result in:

error message: `stash@1 is not a valid reference`

For the longest time I didn't catch that the error message did not contain `{}` for the stash number.

I eventually figured out that I had to quote the stash reference:
`git stash show -p 'stash@{1}'`

Is there some sort of configuration of the shell that I need to set?

I couldn't find any information about the fish shell interpreting `{}` as something else or stripping out the curly brackets.

Comment: Some other shells do this too, e.g., the ancient csh and tcsh. Just quote the braces.

Comment: General rule: anything you want to pass literally to another command, quote it. Even if you don't *need* to, it won't hurt.

Answer (score 5):

As of fish shell 3.1 (released today!), the quoting is no longer required.

Prior to 3.1, the `{1}` is understood as a bracket expansion and so must be quoted to get the literal brackets.

(The behavior was changed in [this issue](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/5869).)